# stat_summary only of specific rows

Tags: r, ggplot2

can I plot the mean of only specific rows in a dataframe?

Let's say, mean `hp` of all cars with `cyl == 6` of the `mtcars` dataset. I know how to plot the mean of all:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(carb, hp)) +
 stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a subset condition within your `ggplot` call:

```
ggplot(mtcars[ mtcars$cyl == 6, ], aes(carb, hp)) +
    stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line")
```